# ibv_post_recv() return -1 instead of errno

Tags: c, linux, infiniband

function ibv_post_recv() return -1, but according to documentation it should return errno.

How to know the fail reason in this case?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 0):

It returns -1 **and** sets errno.
Check the errno value when the function returns.

Comment: errno sets to zero. i.e. success.

Answer (score 0):

What low-level hardware driver are you using?  What version?  I'm guessing it's libmlx4 (Mellanox ConnectX/ConnectX-2/ConnectX-3).

If so, versions >= libmlx4 1.0.2 actually have this fixed -- ibv_post_send() will return an error code rather than -1.

In any case (and this is actually not very dependent of low-level driver -- I think libmthca, libcxgb4, etc. are petty much the same), the reasons that `ibv_post_send()` might return an immediate error are:

- send queue is full (i.e. number of sends posted with uncollected completions is >= size of send queue).
- opcode in send WR is invalid
- number of gather entries is invalid (either <= 0 or > max gs entries specified when send queue was created)
- inline data is bigger than maximum inline data for send queue

**EDIT:** I see I read the question too fast and confused `ibv_post_recv()` and `ibv_post_send()`.  The answer for `ibv_post_recv()` is pretty much the same, just a little simpler.  Basically the only reasons why `ibv_post_recv()` might return an error are:

- receive queue is full
- number of scatter entries in a receive work request is invalid